# How can a link function and controller function share knowledge in an angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular directive that shows payment history. By default, it shows the last 6 payments using the `vm.numberOfPaymentsToDisplay` variable. If you click view more, it adds 10. Now, when a user clicks on another section, there's a listener in the link function that is supposed to reset the number to 6, however `vm` is undefined.

Here's the code:

```
angular.module('nui.settings2.account')
 .directive('paymentHistory', function(){

 function PaymentHistoryController(paymentHistoryService, $filter, $window, $translate){

  const filter = $filter('formatCurrency');

  var vm = this;
  vm.payments = paymentHistoryService.get();
  vm.numberOfPaymentsToDisplay = 6;
  vm.getLastPayment = getLastPayment;
  vm.viewMorePayments = viewMorePayments;
  vm.title = $translate.instant('NUI.SETTINGS.PAYMENT_HISTORY');


  function getLastPayment(){
    const lastTransaction = paymentHistoryService.getLastPayment();
    return lastPaymentInfo = "amount (date)";
  }

  function viewMorePayments(){
    vm.numberOfPaymentsToDisplay = vm.numberOfPaymentsToDisplay + 10;
    return true;
  }
}

function link(scope, element, attrs, [expander, paymentHistory]){
  const containerEl = element.children();
  expander.registerContentContainer(containerEl);
  scope.$on(expander.COLLAPSE_EVENT, () => vm.numberOfPaymentsToDisplay = 6);
  scope.$on("$destroy", () => scope.$emit(expander.CONTAINER_DEREGISTER_EVENT));
  paymentHistory.cancel = () => expander.collapse();
}

return {
  restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: 'nui/settings2/account/billing/payment-history.directive.html',
  controller: PaymentHistoryController,
  link: link,
  require: ['^^settingExpander', 'paymentHistory'],
  controllerAs: 'PaymentHistoryCtrl',
  bindToController: true
};
});
```

How can I set `vm.numberOfPaymentsToDisplay = 6` in the link function even though this knowledge is only known by the controller?

Answer (score 4):

You can add a method to your PaymentHistoryController like setNumberOfPaymentsToDisplay as you inject your PaymentHistoryController into your link function you can call the method like this:

```
paymentHistory.setNumberOfPaymentsToDisplay(6);
```

**Controller code:**

```
function PaymentHistoryController(paymentHistoryService, $filter, $window, $translate){

  const filter = $filter('formatCurrency');

  var vm = this;
  vm.payments = paymentHistoryService.get();
  vm.numberOfPaymentsToDisplay = 6;
  vm.getLastPayment = getLastPayment;
  vm.viewMorePayments = viewMorePayments;
  vm.setNumberOfPaymentsToDisplay = setNumberOfPaymentsToDisplay;
  vm.title = $translate.instant('NUI.SETTINGS.PAYMENT_HISTORY');


  function getLastPayment(){
    const lastTransaction = paymentHistoryService.getLastPayment();
    return lastPaymentInfo = "amount (date)";
  }

  function viewMorePayments(){
    vm.numberOfPaymentsToDisplay = vm.numberOfPaymentsToDisplay + 10;
    return true;
  }

  function setNumberOfPaymentsToDisplay(amount) {
     vm.numberOfPaymentsToDisplay = amount;
  }
}
```

**link code:**

```
function link(scope, element, attrs, [expander, paymentHistory]){
  const containerEl = element.children();
  expander.registerContentContainer(containerEl);
  scope.$on(expander.COLLAPSE_EVENT, () => paymentHistory.setNumberOfPaymentsToDisplay(6));
  scope.$on("$destroy", () => scope.$emit(expander.CONTAINER_DEREGISTER_EVENT));
  paymentHistory.cancel = () => expander.collapse();
}
```

Comment: awesome, I was wondering why I kept getting controller undefined. I should have been using paymentHistory!

Comment: actually wait, I'm still getting setNumberOfPaymentsToDisplay to be undefined. The error is happening in the link code where you pass in 6 as the param.

Comment: sorry I forgot a part: I'll edit my answer, vm.setNumberOfPaymentsToDisplay= setNumberOfPaymentsToDisplay;

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have more options.
the general approach to share data between components is to use a service that is a singleton , a single instance cached and injected by angular everytime you use it inside your component. another valid solution is to emit events.

**Service**:

```
.service('MyService', function(){
 var data;
 this.setData = function(newData){
   data = newData;
 }
 this.getData = function(){
  return data;
 }
})
```

**Events**:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('my.evt', data); //down in the scope chain, visible to any scope
$rootScope.$emit('my.evt', data); //up in the scope chain since is the rootscope only visible to rootScope

$scope.$emit //up in the scope chain
$scope.$broacast //down in the scope chain
```

to listen for events:

```
$rootScope.$on('my.evt', function(evt, data){ //do something }
```

or

```
$scope.$on('my.evt', function(evt, data){ //do something }
```

However in this case you're using the link function to modify your business logic and this is not the the conventional approach, usually the link is used only to handle dom events and to modify the dom. so my personal advice is to refactor your code and put the whole business logic inside the controller

Comment: Are you saying to emit an event from the link fn, and have a listener in the controller that then modifies the business logic?

Comment: would the emit work to communicate between link and controller?

Comment: yes the $rootScope.$emit() will work in this case. but if this variable is globally used inside your app is better wrap it inside a service